# Aws policy to give IAM user access to a specific api gateway api does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-api-gateway-v2

I strongly believe that this has something to do with the ARN format.

I have created a rest API with just a put action and this API would upload files to S3 bucket.

I have created an IAM user called integration_test. Now I want this user to only have one permission which is access to the above api and only allow PUT action. If I grant this user the AWS managed ApiGatewayInvokeFullAccess it works.

This is what I got so far.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke",
                "apigateway:PUT"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws-us-gov:apigateway:us-gov-west-1::/api/account-id:api:id/stages/dev/PUT/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also want to put out that I am on the AWS GOV cloud.

UPDATE - After trying out Willis answer -

If I remove that colon I see an error appearing on the edit screen.
[image]

Comment: Looks like you're almost there, and given that you got it to work with the full access permission, you just need to tweak something before it will work.

Review this example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html#api-gateway-policy-example-apigateway-general

Also review this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/arn-format-reference.html

I notice your resource has "api" instead of "apis" like the docs. Good luck and make sure to update the answer if you figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the action `apigateway:PUT` has no impact because the resource does not belong to the apigateway action.

And I would say that your resource is wrong, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html. Check out the syntax and correct it like `arn:aws-us-gov:execute-api:us-gov-west-1::<api-id>/dev/PUT/*`

Comment: Hello Willi Kisser, I tried as you mentioned and also tried as mentioned on the link you provided. I am still not able to execute the api.

Comment: @Sumchans Could you provide more details like your updated IAM Policy or the error message. 

Btw. where do you use this IAM User? Is this IAM User used in a service, like AWS Lambda? If it is so, do you added an assumeRole permission? Like

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}`

Like described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html

Comment: I use this IAM user just for using the API gateway service to upload images to S3 bucket.  I will be using the This IAM users access key and secret access key to connect to API Gateway from Salesforce. I can say that if I provide AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess permission to this IAM user then everything works fine. BUt I dont want to provide all access to this user but just to this specific API.

Comment: Here is my latest policy `{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": [
    "execute-api:Invoke",
    "apigateway:PUT"
   ],
   "Resource": "arn:aws-us-gov:apigateway:us-gov-west-1::account-id:api-id/dev/PUT/*"
  }
 ]
}`

Comment: There is one colon too many in the resource id before account-id.

Your setup is to upload a file via AWS API Gateway to S3 Bucket by using an IAM User in Salesforce, right? If so, you usually need to permit your API Gateway to access the S3 Bucket.

If you use the AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess permission, how do you test if your setup works? How do you upload a file? Via the invoke URL of the API Gateway?
Pls. add more details about your infrastructure setup and context about what you intended to do!

Comment: @Willis I have a snip of the error to the original post when I remove the colon. The permission to upload files to S3 is already there for API Gateway. I am not planning to use AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess, I just want to use the policy that I created above for the IAM user to access API Gateway. The reason I mentioned on using the AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess was just for testing. When I add AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess to the IAM user it works, but if my IAM user just has the policy that I created it wouldn't work.